# Expired cookies not clearing in firefox

Tags: firefox, cookies

I am using cookies with a set expiration date.
Why are expired cookies not being removed from the storage in dev tools in Firefox?
When they expire, in the website context they do not exist anymore but they don't get removed from the storage.
In Chrome, as soon as they expire they are removed from storage.

I have read that session cookies that are supposed to clear on browser exit do not because of the session restore functionality of Firefox. Is this what is causing that behaviour?

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I've also been struggling with this for a while. I couldn't find an elegant solution to clear them, but I did find a bit of a 'hacky' workaround.

The only way I found to remove a Firefox expired cookie from my app is to first set the cookie again without the 'expires' option (or a date in the future) and then delete it.

For context, I'm using js-cookies in a React app.
So first I set my cookie using:

```
Cookies.set('name', 'cookieValue', { expires: dateInTheFuture });
```

Once the cookie is expired and I want to clear it, I use:

```
Cookies.set('name', '');
Cookies.remove('name');
```